# R keras model eval/predict error: Error in do.call(object$evaluate, args) : 'what' must be a function or character string

Tags: r, keras, predict

I have a keras model (using R) and TF as backend as follows

```
history <- model %>% fit( train_X1,train_y,batch_size=100,
               epochs=80,validation_split = 0.2,
               shuffle=TRUE)

> class(model)
[1] "keras.models.Sequential"         "keras.engine.training.Model"    
[3] "keras.engine.topology.Container" "keras.engine.topology.Layer"    
[5] "python.builtin.object"
```

The dimensions are as follows:

```
> dim(train_X1)
[1] 4893   64   64    1
> dim(train_y)
[1] 4893   12
```

I am trying to evaluate and predict first on train set and then on test set.

```
model %>% evaluate(train_X1,train_y)
pred <- model %>% predict_classes(train_X1)
```

however I am getting the following error on running the evaluate command:

```
Error in do.call(object$evaluate, args) :  'what' must be a function or character string
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. To replicate this issue, add "install_keras()" and run the script through plumber (which turns the r script into a REST API. More info here: www.rplumber.io). Every time I run "install_keras()" from within plumber my whole keras are guaranteed to break. Even re-install keras and tensorflow won't fix it. I had to re-install the whole R...

Comment: I wonder if you have not loaded another package that defines `evaluate`. For example the `evaluate` package. Try replacing `evaluate` with `RKeras::evaluate`... and maybe provide runnable code, including relevant library calls, in your question.